# Removing date in the title

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[16pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={16.5cm,25.2cm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

\newcommand{\RN}[1]{%
  \textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}%
}

\newenvironment{claim}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Claim:}\space#1}{}
\newenvironment{claimproof}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Proof:}\space#1}{\hfill $\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\title{\textbf{Research Statement}}
\author{Xxx Yyyy}
\date{August 6, 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\large

\end{document}
```

I am wondering how to remove the date that appears after the author? If you remove `\date{}` then it still appears after compilation.

Also, how can I add enumerated sections in the center?

Answer (score 5):

Just call `\date{}` instead of commenting it out.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know this!

Comment: Neither did I, I bought a sledgehammer to crack a nut. +1